# How to change the color of an anchor tag in a list for being active while already set to another color?

Tags: html, css

I have already set the text color of anchor tag in a list as BLACK in the CSS file. Now I want to declare a list item as active and change its text color, but it doesn't work. Help please!

Here's the preset color:

```
#already-set li a
{
    font: normal 14px Arial;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;

    color: black;

    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:26px;
    padding-left:5px;            
}
```

And here's the code to change active list item color:

```
a#active
{
    background-color: #d11250;

    color: white;

    font-weight:bold;   
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="already-set">                               
  <li><a href="#" id="active"> List Item </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting confused with the `a:active`.

Please check this **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/5qL5E/)** which will make it a bit more clear. I have added jQuery to change the active element on the fly when clicked.

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    // remove classes from all
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#already-set li a {
  font: normal 14px Arial;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a.active {
  background-color: #d11250;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="already-set">
  <li><a href="#"> List Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active"> List Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"> List Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The text color remains black because of the css in the list. If you want to change the text color to white in the selected element please make the following change as the **[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/5qL5E/1/)**

Change `a.active` to `#already-set li a.active`.

Comment: I'm not following you! 
Could you be more specific?!

Comment: Edited my answer please check if that solves your problem now.

Comment: @Thanos - Thanks! That was an extensive answer, but my question was about something else! 
As you can see, when you choose the list item, the background changes but not the its text color. How do you change the text color to white while not changing the preset color which is black?

Comment: @Cyrus you will need to change the list font color and not the link color, check my new edit

Comment: @Thanos - Yes, that was it! It solved the problem :) 
You are a dear!

Answer (score 1):

Change `a#active` to `a:active` this will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work! 
When change that, it deactivates whatever changes I made to the list!

Comment: #active{color:white;}