# CSS Nav bar current/active color link

Tags: css

First homepage. Nav bar color for current page isn't working. Suggestions? CSS below. Thanks.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Turf.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="Turf2.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Turf3.html">STAFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="Turf4.html">LINKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Turf5.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav{
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-width:1px 0;
list-style:none;
margin:20;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
}

.nav li{
display:inline-block;
color:#493D26;
font-size: 15px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}

.nav a{
display:inline-block;
border-width:1px 0;
padding:15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#493D26;
font-size: 17px;
font-style:bold;
text-transform:capitalize;    
}

ul.nav a:hover{ 
color: #6CBB3C; 
}

ul.nav a:current{
color: #6CBB3C;
}
```

Comment: see this question,may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502750/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-anchor-tag-in-a-list-for-being-active-while-alread

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css code also.

a:active : when you click on the link and hold it (active!).
a:visited : when the link has already been visited.

If you want the link corresponding to current page to be highlighted, you can define some specific style to the link -

```
ul.nav a:visited {
color: #6CBB3C;
}
```

Add this new class only to the corresponding li (link), either on server-side or on client-side (using javascript).

Comment: provide relevent html?

Comment: Ah thanks but I think I'm too much of a noobie to get into JS.

Answer (score 0):

check the snippet..

```css
.nav {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #493D26;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #493D26;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
  color: #6CBB3C;
}
ul.nav a:visited {
  color: #6CBB3C;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Turf2.html">PRODUCTS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Turf3.html">STAFF</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Turf4.html">LINKS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Turf5.html">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery trick:

You should add jQuery library file fist:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav li a").each(function()
    {
        if(this.href==window.location.href)
        {
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and add this css:

```
ul.nav a.current{
    color: #6CBB3C;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and it didn't work either - I expect it's my lack of know how about JS.

Comment: Hi Katethegreat, I have edit my answer it's now more usefull,
You have to simply copy this script now.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear..

Try `.nav ul` instead of `ul.nav` :)